# Updating file permission to "owner" fails with 500 internal error

Tags: google-drive-api

for our domain, there's a need to transfer files in a particular folder from one user to an admin account.  The admin account has the "writer" role on all the files.  Both users are in the same domain.

I'm using domain-wide delegation as the authorization method.

When updating the admin account's permission from "writer" to "owner", the program returns with 500 Internal Error.  Any help will be appreciated.  Thanks!

```
public static Drive getDriveService(String userEmail) throws GeneralSecurityException,IOException, URISyntaxException {
  HttpTransport httpTransport = new NetHttpTransport();
  JacksonFactory jsonFactory = new JacksonFactory();
  Collection<String> scope = new ArrayList<String>();
  scope.add(DriveScopes.DRIVE);

  GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
      .setTransport(httpTransport)
      .setJsonFactory(jsonFactory)
      .setServiceAccountId(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL)
      .setServiceAccountScopes(scope)
      .setServiceAccountUser(userEmail)
      .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(
          new java.io.File(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PKCS12_FILE_PATH))
      .build();

  Drive service = new Drive.Builder(httpTransport, jsonFactory, null)
      .setHttpRequestInitializer(credential).build();
  return service;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        Drive userDriveService = getDriveService(ADMIN_ACCT_EMAIL);
        ChildList list = userDriveService.children().list(folderId).setQ("not '" + ADMIN_ACCT_EMAIL + "' in owners").execute();
        java.util.List<ChildReference> children = list.getItems();
                //Simplified for testing
        ChildReference child = children.get(0);
        String fileId = child.getId();
        String permId = userDriveService.permissions().getIdForEmail(ADMIN_ACCT_EMAIL).execute().getId();
        Permission perm = userDriveService.permissions().get(fileId, permId).execute();
        perm.setRole("owner");
        userDriveService.permissions().update(fileId, permId, perm).setTransferOwnership(true).execute();
    } catch (GeneralSecurityException | IOException | URISyntaxException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Resolved the issue:  Had to get the original owner of the file, get drive service with the original owner's email, then use that driveservice to update file permission.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Realized that I should have been using the owner's email to get the driveservice.  This worked after changing that one line.  Thanks.

```
    Drive userDriveService = getDriveService(ORIGINAL_OWNER_EMAIL);
```